# Ubuntu wierd sound of connected device

Tags: 18.04, sound, devices

On my fresh Ubuntu 18.04 I keep hearing sound that usually appears while connecting usb stick or something. Like something was connecting and disconnecting all the time, every few minutes.
What do I to check what that is?

Comment: Should edit your question with computer make and model.  Have similar problem with a random chirp, but not related to USB.  Would try dmesg log when it happens.

Answer (score 1):

Run the `dmesg` command on the command line to see the kernel log. If it is really a device connecting and disconnecting then it will be logged there.

Answer (score 1):

The `sudo udevadm monitor` command gives me the following output all the time.

```
KERNEL[16948.130453] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:00/PNP0C09:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/ADP1 (power_supply)
UDEV  [16948.134911] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:00/PNP0C09:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/ADP1 (power_supply)
KERNEL[17020.165977] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:00/PNP0C09:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/ADP1 (power_supply)
UDEV  [17020.170337] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:00/PNP0C09:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/ADP1 (power_supply)
KERNEL[17023.290368] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:00/PNP0C09:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/ADP1 (power_supply)
UDEV  [17023.294819] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:00/PNP0C09:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/ADP1 (power_supply)
```

After all I found out that I had some charger input problems. Disconnecting the charger makes that noice over again.